# Cannot open database error when logging into SQL server from Mule using jdbc

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mule, database-connection

I have setup the generic database configuration in Mule and have set the JDBC connection string to

```
jdbc:sqlserver:// ${db.host};databaseName=${db.name};user=${db.user};password=${db.password};integratedSecurity=true;
```

The database requires Windows Authentication which is different to my own personal windows login so the db.user value is set to DOMAIN\\userId and I have added the auth dll file to the native library of the SQL Server jar in the build path.

[image: Java Build Path]

It returns the error message below:

[image: Test Connection Failed]

The password does contain special characters (!^#) but I can get a "Test successful" message when I test the connection without a database name in the jdbc connection string.

I can however login using the same credentials and access the database using SQL Management Studio.

Does anyone know what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not MSSQL admin but i've got something like that and it works - maybe you could use it somehow.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://{host}\{domain}:1433;databaseName={db.name};user={user};password={password}
```